# C# - How to place a given number of random mines in an array

Tags: c#

I'm new to c#. I have a task to make a type of minesweeper, but which immediately opens a solution.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.Write("Enter the width of the field: ");
            int q = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            Console.Write("Enter the length of the field: ");
            int w = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            Console.Write("Enter the number of bombs: ");
            int c = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());


            Random rand = new Random();

            var charArray = new char[q, w];
            var intArray = new int[q, w];
            for (int i = 0; i < q; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < w; j++)
                {
                    intArray[i, j] = rand.Next(2);
                    charArray[i, j] = intArray[i, j] == 0 ? '_' : '*';
                    Console.Write(charArray[i, j]);
                }
                Console.WriteLine();
            }

        }

    }
}
```

Two arrays should be output. Everything should be closed on the first one, that is, there should be only the characters: _ and *

0 - these are places without mines, I replaced them with a symbol _

1 - these are places with mines, I replaced them with an asterisk symbol, but they do not accept the number of mines entered by the user. And it is necessary that there are as many "*" characters as there are mines.

And in the second array there should be an already open solution of the game. That is, the cells next to which there are mines should take a number meaning the number of mines next to this cell.

Please help me..

[Compiling the current code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TkWMu.png)

Comment: Well, it does not look like the variable `c`, i.e. … _”the number of bombs”_ is used anywhere in the code. And I am not sure how having the user “enter” the number of bombs is needed if… _” … it is necessary that there are as many "*" characters as there are mines.”_ … ? … the second requirement is solely dependent on the width and height of the board. Are you sure these requirements are correct?

Answer (score 1):

```
        
        Random random = new Random();
        while(c > 0)
        {
            var rq = random.Next(q);
            var rw = random.Next(w);
            if(intArray[rq,rw] == 0)
            {
                intArray[rq, rw] = 1;
                c--;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest dividing the problem in smaller manageable chunks. For instance, you can place the bombs in a initial step, and on a second step build the solution. You can build the solution at the same time you place the bombs, although for clarity you can do it after.

Naming of variables is also important. If you prefer using single letter variable names, I believe that's fine for the problem limits, however I would use meaningful letters easier to remember. eg: `W` and `H` for the width and height of the board, and `B` for the total number of bombs.

The first part of the problem then can be described as placing `B` bombs in a `W`x`H` board. So instead of having nested `for` statements that enumerate `W`x`H` times, it's better to have a `while` loop that repeats the bomb placing logic as long as you have remaining bombs.
Once you generate a new random location on the board, you have to check you haven't placed a bomb there already. You can have an auxiliary function `HasBomb` that checks that:

```cs
bool HasBomb(char[,] charArray, int x, int y)
{
    return charArray[x,y] == '*';
}
```

I'll leave error checking out, this function being private can rely on the caller sending valid coordinates.

Then the bomb placing procedure can be something like:

```cs
int remainingBombs = B;
while (remainingBombs > 0)
{
    int x = rand.Next(W);
    int y = rand.Next(H);
    if (!HasBomb(charArray, x, y)
    {
        charArray[x,y] = '*';
        remainingBombs--;
    }
}
```

At this point you may figure out another concern. If the number `B` of bombs to place is larger than the available positions on the board `W`x`H`, then you wont be able to place the bombs on the board. You'll have to check for that restriction when requesting the values for `W`, `H` and `B`.

Then in order to create the array with the number of bombs next to each position, you'll need some way to check for all the neighbouring positions to a given one. If the position is in the middle of the board it has 8 neighbour positions, if it's on an edge it has 5, and if it's on a corner it has 3. Having a helper function return all the valid neighbour positions can be handy.

```cs
IEnumerable<(int X, int Y)> NeighbourPositions(int x, int y, int W, int H)
{
    bool leftEdge = x == 0;
    bool topEdge = y == 0;
    bool rightEdge = x == W - 1;
    bool bottomEdge = y == H - 1;

    if (!leftEdge && !topEdge)
        yield return (x-1, y-1);
    if (!topEdge)
        yield return (x, y-1);
    if (!rightEdge && !topEdge)
        yield return (x+1, y-1);
    if (!leftEdge)
        yield return (x-1, y);
    if (!rightEdge)
        yield return (x+1, y);
    if (!leftEdge && !bottomEdge)
        yield return (x-1, y+1);
    if (!bottomEdge)
        yield return (x, y+1);
    if (!rightEdge && !bottomEdge)
        yield return (x+1, y+1)   
}
```

This function uses Iterators and touples. If you feel those concepts are too complex as you said are new to C#, you can make the function return a list with coordinates instead.

Now the only thing left is to iterate over the whole `intArray` and increment the value on each position for each neighbour bomb you find.

```cs
for (int x = 0; x < W; x++)
{
    for (int y = 0; y < H; y++)
    {
        foreach (var n in NeighbourPositions(x, y, W, H))
        {
            if (HasBomb(charArray, n.X, n.Y))
                intArray[x,y]++;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The answers here are mostly about generating random `x` and random `y` put in loop and trying to put the mine into empty cells. It is ok solution, but if you think of it, it is not that sufficient. Every time you try to find a new random cell, there is chance that cell is already a mine. This is pretty much alright, if you don't put too many mines into your field, but if you put some greater number of mines, this event can occur quite often. This means that the loop might take longer than usually. Or, theoretically, if you wanted to put 999 mines into 1000 cell field, it would be really hard for the loop to fill all the necessary cells, especially for the last mine. Now, I am not saying that the solutions here are bad, I think, it's really alright solution for many people. But if someone wanted a little bit efficient solution, I have tried to crate it.

### Solution

In this solution, you iterate each cell and try to calculate a probability of the mine to be placed there. I have come up with this easy formula, which calculates the probability:

[image: \frac{mineCount-minePlacedCount}{cellCount-cellExploredCount}]

Every time you try to place a mine into one cell, you calculate this formula and compare it to random generated number.

```cs
bool isMine = random.NextDouble() < calcProbability();
```